# How does this Code show that the Mouse has clicked?

Tags: java, awt

Seen this somewhere in StackOverflow. Just want to know how it  works...

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
}
```

x and y are coordinates and can be shown to screen using JLabel, but the method name is mouseClicked. How does java know the mouse has been clicked?

(Hope this makes sense)...

Comment: Could you please provide complete code block, singe line does not provide enough context. I presume that's why you have the hope that it makes sense!

Comment: @HossainKhan I disagree. This is a code sample that the OP found somewhere, so they may not even have the full context, and even if they did, they're evidently unaware that this is likely an event handler, so they wouldn't know where to look for the relevant context. (If they *did* know that, they presumably wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place). The question seems reasonable to me, especially if the OP hasn't worked with front ends much before - this code sample would probably appear quite strange if so.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica sure point noted.

Answer (score 4):

The method `mouseClicked` is *likely* from `java.awt.event.MouseListener` interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)

> A listener is a type of callback that follows the observer pattern, something happens, you get notified.

You can attach listener to items that support it. For example:

```java
MouseListener listener = new MouseListener() { /* see example code below */ };
JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a clickable lable");
label.addMouseListener(listener);
```

See the following answer to get more info and reference to reading articles.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415300/132121

---

@transformer here is an empty implementation of the `MouseListener` you would create in Java code.

```java
MouseListener listener = new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // This is the method where you would get your callback
        // whenever somebody clicked on the view that has this listener
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
};
```

Comment: how would I get the example code to work? **MouseListener listener = ... your listener;** What is "... your listener"?

Comment: @Transformer Added code for the `MouseListener` implementation, see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is an event handler. In order for it to work, it has to be "attached" to something in the front end (most likely a button, but it could be another UI element too).

Exactly how this works depends on which UI framework is being used, but since this is Java I assume it's most likely AWT. You can find more details in tutorials, e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awt/awt_mouse_event.htm).

Incidentally, how significant the name is depends on which UI framework this is from. In Android, WPF, and ASP.NET, for example, the name of event handlers could theoretically be anything, it's mostly just a matter of convention (not actual requirement) what you call it. (Obviously, you have to be consistent with the name, though). As pointed out in the comments, though, in AWT this name is actually likely significant due to the class that contains it implementing an interface.

Comment: I think the name is likely significant since it's part of the `java.awt.event.MouseListener` interface.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon That's quite possible - I've truthfully never worked with that framework, mostly just WPF, ASP.NET, and Android. I'll edit.

Comment: I used  this **import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;** to get the mouse click to work. Is the MouseListener interface implemented in MouseAdapter?

Comment: @Transformer yes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html