# What do I need to implement to make the JLabels clickable?

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

so I created a 2 JLabels which display an icon but now I want that if you click on of the JLabels it produces a text which is displayed on the JFrame. What I know is that you can add some kind of Listener, but the ActionListener doesnt work, so I searched more and came to the MouseListener but I don't understand the explanations and the projects are way more complicated to my. Everthing Im copy pasting is underlined in red.

```
void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
```

So i came to this method and it looks kinda similar to the ActionListener method, but again, i dont know which correct Java class i should import or should i "classname implement MouseListener"?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main1{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ImageIcon frameBG = new ImageIcon("res/bg.png");
        ImageIcon dogIcon = new ImageIcon("res/dog.png");
        ImageIcon catIcon = new ImageIcon("res/cat.png");

        JLabel bgLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel dogLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel catLabel = new JLabel();

        bgLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 250);
        bgLabel.setIcon(frameBG);

        dogLabel.setBounds(50, 30, 150, 150);
        dogLabel.setIcon(dogIcon);
        

        catLabel.setBounds(210, 30, 150, 150);
        catLabel.setIcon(catIcon);
        
        
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cat and Dog Clicker");
        frame.setSize(400, 250);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        
        frame.add(dogLabel);
        frame.add(catLabel);
        frame.add(bgLabel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Instead of a JLabel use a `JButton`. Then you can add an ActionListener to the buttons to handle the clicking. You can make the button look like a label by setting a few properties of the button. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414765/131872

Comment: _I searched more and came to the MouseListener but I don't understand the explanations_ then the way to go is to learn how to use mouseListeners :) Starting f.i. at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
bgLabel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
bgLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("click");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("press");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("entered");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("exit");
    }});
```